# Como pegar dados relacionados em Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá.
Tenho uma aplicação onde `User` has_many `Status`. And `Status` has_many `Likes`.

Como pego o total de likes que um usário tem? Por exemplo, ele tem 2 status com 10 likes cada um, que da um total de 20 likes.
Como pego este valor?

Meu model está simples:

`User has_many Status`

`Status has_many Likes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`has_many through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class User
  has_many statuses
  has_many likes, through: :statuses
end
```

A palavra *through* significa "através", então a instrução acima significa "possui muitos *likes* através de *statuses*".

As duas chamadas estarão disponíveis:

```
@user.statuses
@user.likes
```

No segundo caso, o ActiveRecord se encarregará de fazer o `INNER JOIN`.

Algumas *queries*:

```
@user.likes                  # Todos os likes do usuário
@user.statuses.find(1).likes # Todos os likes do status de id=1, que pertence ao usuário
@user.statuses.first.likes   # Primeiro
@user.statuses.last.likes    # Último
                             # etc
```

Não deixe de ler [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado, mais uma vez Andrey. Só uma pergunta: Nesse caso, eu não conseguiria pegar quantos likes o usuário deu né?
Ex: Se eu colocasse somente `user has many likes` e colocasse `@user.likes` ele me daria todas as curtidas enviadas. Quando uso o `through` ele me da todas as recebidas pelo Status. Teria algum jeito de conseguir os 2? Talvez nomear diferente?

Comment: @IgorMartins Editei a pergunta adicionando algumas *queries*. É isso que você quer?